# Separating a sort by filter/select

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form where i search for products on a few subjects, i also have a html select working with a php switch to enable the ability to sort the order of the results. this currently works in the search form and i want to make the sort by html select to work without clicking the the search button and to run the correct select option every time its changed and to instantly change the order of the products to match the select option.

Here is the HTML:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 's.index', 'method' => 'GET']) !!}
                <div class="form-group">

                    {!! Form::label('productsname', 'Search By Name:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('productsname', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('categories_id', 'Search By Category:') !!}
                <select class="form-control" name="categories_id" >
                    <option value=""></option>

                    @foreach($types as $type)

                        <option value="{{$type->id}}">{{$type->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = col-md-6>

        <div class="form-group">




                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="SortbyList" >
                        <option value="1">Highest Avg</option>
                        <option value="2">Lowest Avg</option>
                        <option value="3">Another Sort option</option>
                        <option value="2">another sort option</option>
                    </select>
                    {!! Form::submit('Find Products', array('class' => ' btn-lg btn-block')) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    //

    $productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('products.id');

    switch ($request->SortbyList) {
        case 1:
            $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');
            break;
        case 2:
            $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 3:
            $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
            break;
        case 4:
            $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'ASC');
            break;
            default:
                $productsQuery = $productsQuery->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');


    }



    $name=$request->input('productname');
    $location=$request->input('categories_id');



    if(!empty($name)){
        $sightsQuery->where('productname', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%')->get();
    }
    if(!empty($location)){
        $sightsQuery->where('categories_id', $request->input('categories_id') )->get();
    }

    $products= $productsQuery->paginate(8);



    return view('p.search')->withproducts($products);

}
```

Comment: what is the problem? what do you expect?

Comment: I want the select as a stand alone rather than in the form thats searching it on button press at the minute. I want to be able to click a select option and the page responds straight away with the results from the search. if you need an example, think of most shopping cart website they have a sort by A-Z etc. i want to be able to have a sort by separate like that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to change the order without clicking on the submit button (and so, without changing/reloading the page)?

PHP can not dynamically update your page, but [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) can.

Comment: how would i do that? examples?